# How do I set use-package-always-pin?

Tags: package, package-repositories, use-package

Emacs noob here, I want to use `melpa-stable` whenever possible for my packages.

`use-package` has an option for this, `use-package-always-pin`.

> By default package.el prefers melpa over melpa-stable due to the versioning (> evil-20141208.623 evil-1.0.9), so even if you are tracking only a single package from melpa, you will need to tag all the non-melpa packages with the appropriate archive. If this really annoys you, then you can set use-package-always-pin to set a default.

How am I supposed to set this?

The documentation for the variable is:

```
use-package-always-pin is a variable defined in `use-package.el'.
Its value is nil

Documentation:
Treat every package as though it had specified `:pin SYM.

You can customize this variable.
```

Since you would `:pin` like this

```el
(use-package smooth-scrolling
  :pin melpa-stable)
```

I would assume that it would one of these

```el
(setq use-package-always-pin melpa-stable)
(setq use-package-always-pin 'melpa-stable)
```

but either one (tried separately) gets me the error:

```
Symbol's value as variable is void: melpa-stable
```

If I start emacs and then eval `(setq use-package-always-pin 'melpa-stable)` it seems to work as expected. I would guess it was some kind of load order issue, but I'm pretty clueless about how that works.

I tried:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'use-package
  (setq use-package-always-pin 'melpa-stable))
```

No luck.

Comment: Could you try `(setq use-package-always-pin "melpa-stable")`?

Comment: There seem to be some issues with `use-package` and `:pin` right now: [#343](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/issues/343) has some explanation which references [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2989/5172) which states: “`package-pinned-packages` must be set **before** calling `package-refresh-contents`”.

Answer (score 2):

The `use-package-always-pin` variable should be set to a string. Setting it prior to your `(use-package)` is supposed to be how you use it. It’s meant to provide the default value so that you don’t have to set `:pin` a bunch of times. For example:

```
;; Automatically :ensure each use-package.
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)
;; Default value for :pin in each use-package.
(setq use-package-always-pin "melpa-stable")

(use-package editorconfig
  :config (editorconfig-mode 1))

(use-package js2-mode
  :pin "melpa" ;; Use unstable version.
  :mode ("\\.js\\'" . js2-jsx-mode)
  :interpreter ("node" . js2-jsx-mode))
```

That is supposed to work, but `:pin` and `:ensure` do not work optimally in `use-package` (at least as of 2017-06-24), so you may have mixed results.