# Gnus cannot start external w3m: no such file or directory

Tags: osx, gnus, shell-command, w3m

while I am using Emacs as an editor for years on my Macbook (OSX 10.13), I only recently started again to launch external commands by using Gnus. While [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/198282/8081) helped me to fix calls to `uncompface`, it is still failing for `w3m`:

```
Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, w3m
```

Actually in the `*Messages*` buffer I see

```
mm-setup-w3m: Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, w3m
```

- both `uncompface` and `w3m` are installed using `brew` in `/usr/local/bin`
- my `$PATH` is defined in `~/.bash_profile`
- and it was also defined for graphical apps with `sudo launchctl config user path $PATH`
- if I check in Emacs with `getenv`, the path does contain `/usr/local/bin`

What am I missing?

I remember before finishing with 10.13 (my MacBook is now unsupported by Apple) that configuring `$PATH` for apps is a periodic pain in the *ss, I previously used a `.plist` for launchd that is now unsupported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you installed is the package that contains the command-line tool `w3m`. But you also need the package that implements the Emacs interface to (the command-line tool) `w3m`.

This package is also commonly called `w3m`, which might explain the confusion. The Emacs package can be found on MELPA, so assuming you have MELPA as one of your package sources, you should be able to say `M-x package-install RET w3m RET` and you should be all set.

If for whatever reason you can't use the Emacs package system, you can install it by hand. See the [Emacs Wiki here](https://wikemacs.org/wiki/W3m-el) and [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/emacs-w3m) for an explanation and details on how to get it.

EDIT: Check the value of `package-archives` - I see the package in `melpa-unstable`, so you need an entry like `("melpa-unstable" . "http://melpa.org/packages/")` in it, and then do `M-x package-refresh`.

EDIT: The OP reports that the package was found in the "normal" MELPA archive, so the previous EDIT can be partially disregarded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. While I did not installed many packages I do have melpa configured `package-archives` is set to `(("gnu" . "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")
 ("melpa-stable" . "http://stable.melpa.org/packages/"))` I do not see `w3m` in the available packages. Investigation is still pending.

Comment: I think you need `melpa-unstable`: I updated the answer.

Comment: Without switching to unstable, using the "normal" melpa repo did the trick. I used [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/2989/226) to setup a ponderated multi repo-setup. Thanks!